# Como fazer submit em um formulário com input text e dois inputs file?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Fiz um formulário de cadastro onde o usuário deve preencher nome e CPF , e anexar uma foto do RG e outra de uma selfie.

Já criei o banco de dados no **mysql**, porém o `submit` não funciona. Quando eu retiro os inputs file, ai funciona.

No **mysql** criei duas colunas do tipo **blob** para receber as duas imagens.

Alguém sabe porque o submit não funciona? A tela não atualiza , simplesmente não acontece nada.

Segue o código do form abaixo.

```
<form id="main-contact-form" action="cadastroAdd.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" placeholder="Nome completo" required onkeyup="maiusculas()" autofocus>&nbsp;<b><font color="red">*</font></b><input type="hidden" name="prazo" id="prazo" ><br><br>
    <input type="text" name="cpf" id="cpf" placeholder="CPF" required OnKeyPress="formatar('###.###.###-##', this)" maxlength="14">&nbsp;<b><font color="red"> Menor de idade ou não tem CPF <input type="checkbox" name="menor"    id="menor" value="-dependente"/>*</font></b><br>*Caso seja menor de idade e ainda não possua CPF, insira o CPF do Responsável. Vale ressaltar que a retirada do documento só poderá ser feita pelo titular do CPF cadastrado.<br><br>
    <input type="text" name="nascimento" id="nascimento" placeholder="Data de Nascimento" required OnKeyPress="formatar('##/##/####', this)" maxlength="10">&nbsp;<b><font color="red">*</font></b>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="telefone" id="telefone" placeholder="Telefone(Whatsapp)" required OnKeyPress="formatar('##-#####-####', this)" maxlength="13">&nbsp;<b><font color="red">*</font></b><br>
    (99-99999-9999)
    <br><br>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="E-mail"><br><br>
    Adicione uma foto de rosto: <input type="file" name="foto" id="foto" class="anexo">&nbsp;<b><font color="red">*</font></b><br><br>
    Adicione uma imagem do seu documento com foto(RG ou CNH): <input type="file" name="documento" id="documento" class="anexo">&nbsp;<b><font color="red">*</font></b><br><br>      
    <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar">
</form> <br><br>
```

### cadastroAdd.php

```
$conexao->query("set names utf8");
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$cpf = $_POST['cpf'];
$nascimento = $_POST['nascimento'];
$telefone = $_POST['telefone'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$prazo = $_POST['prazo'];
$foto = $FILE['foto'];
$documento = $FILE['documento'];
$menor = $_POST['menor'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO `epiz_24359771_paraqueradical`.`usuarios` (`nome`, `cpf`, `nascimento`, `telefone`, `email`, `prazo`)  values ('$nome','$menor''$cpf','$nascimento','$telefone','$email','$prazo','$foto','$documento')";
$salvar = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql);
$linhas = mysqli_affected_rows($conexao);
mysqli_close($conexao);
?>
<?php
if ($linhas == 1) {
    echo "Cadastro efetuado com Sucesso!!";


} else {
    print "Cadastro não efetuado.";

}

?>
<a class="botao" href="cadastro.php"><input type="button" id="voltar" value="VOLTAR"></a>
```

Comment: Você quer com ou sem `type=files`?

Comment: com type files . quero que envie tudo para o mysql que ja criei. ou seja. as 2 fotos e os dados do usuário

Comment: Adicione os inputs que deseja no seu código...

Comment: já estão ai. são 5 inputs text , 1 checkbox e 2 files.

Comment: Como está seu `cadastroAdd.php` este é o arquivo que está recebendo e que deve processar a requisição enviada pelo form e salvar os dados no mysql.

Comment: Não estou vendo a alteração do `enctype`...

Comment: Tem problemas no cadastro... `'$menor''$cpf'` não tem virgula no insert desses dados. Além disso você está tentando inserir em 6 campos e está enviando 9 variáveis... Isso só no insert. Acho que seria melhor você postar os erros que são mostrados.

Answer (score 1):

Amigo por padrão a propriedade do formulário `enctype` tem o valor `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Para o envio de arquivos você precisa especificar `enctype=multipart/form-data`.

```
<form id="main-contact-form" action="cadastroAdd.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: inclui o enctype="multipart/form-data", e nada

Comment: Edite sua questão com as alterações feitas...

Comment: editei lá em cima

Comment: Qual o nome do arquivo que contém o formulário?

Comment: ...... cadastro.php

Comment: Tem problemas no insert do cadastro.

Comment: Inclua no topo dos 2 arquivos `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);`  E coloque os errors...

Comment: isso é php? coloco no topo dos dois arquivos? cadastro.php e cadastroAdd.php

Comment: inseri nos dois. mas ainda nada acontece. parece que o erro está no arquivo cadastro.php, pois não está nem submentendo. ele nem busca a página do action. quando retiro os input file  funciona

Answer (score 1):

Allan, haviam muitos erros de digitação nos seus arquivos. Os corrigi pra vc.
Vc estava utilizando

> $FILE

sendo que o correto é `$_FILES[]`.

Outra coisa no seu `insert` havia um erro entre

> '$menor''$cpf',

faltando uma vírgula.

Para você ter um retorno do seu sistema para quando HOUVER erro na sua consulta, `insert, update, delete` etc vc utiliza no final das suas `mysqli_query()` o seguinte comando:

> `or mysqli_error();`

Com isto, caso exista erro na sua query te retornará erro.

Corrigi o seu arquivo cadastroAdd.php:

```
<?php

//ini_set("display_errors",true);

ini_set('default_charset', 'utf-8');
include("conexao.php");

/* AQUI ESTÃO OS DADOS VINDOS DO FORMULARIO*/
echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($_POST);
echo "</pre>";

echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($_FILES);
echo "</pre>";

$conexao->query("set names utf8");
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$cpf = $_POST['cpf'];
$nascimento = $_POST['nascimento'];
$telefone = $_POST['telefone'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$prazo = $_POST['prazo'];
$foto = $_FILES['foto'];
$documento = $_FILES['documento'];
$menor = $_POST['menor'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO `epiz_24359771_paraqueradical`.`usuarios` (`nome`, `cpf`, `nascimento`, `telefone`, `email`, `prazo`)  values ('$nome','$menor','$cpf','$nascimento','$telefone','$email','$prazo','$foto','$documento')";
$salvar = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql) or mysqli_error();
$linhas = mysqli_affected_rows($conexao);
mysqli_close($conexao);
?>
<?php
if ($linhas == 1) {
    echo "Cadastro efetuado com Sucesso!!";


} else {
    print "Cadastro não efetuado.";

}

?>

<a class="botao" href="cadastro.php">
<input type="button" id="voltar" value="VOLTAR">
</a>
```

Note que eu usei `var_dump($_POST)` << este mostra todos os `POST` que estão vindo do seu formulário, assim como utilizei `var_dump($_FILES)` aonde mostra os arquivos.

> COMENTE ESSES VAR_DUMPS para seu código funcionar normalmente.

Comment: vou tentar aqui, mas a questão da vírgula não é pra ter mesmo. pois quero que na coluna do mysql entre as duas informações. ou seja, o valor da variavel $menor ,seguido da variável $cpf. essas duas informações no mesmo campo.

Comment: Então Leandro Alfredo, a questão é que a página não vai para o cadastroAdd.php.

Comment: clico em enviar e não acontece nada. por isso acho que o erro está em algum lugar em cadastro.php.

Quando retiro os input file do form. os dados são gravados normalmente no mysql. mas precisava que ele enviasse as fotos também.

teria como fazer com javascript?

Comment: cara, se vc colocou o seu código ali encima não tem erro nenhum no seu arquivo. Vc está errando ai. Conforme o que você passou e o q eu postei está perfeitamente funcionando.

Comment: Tem mais erros no `insert`... Ele está tentando inserir em 6 campos declarados um total de 9 valores diferentes... isso gera o erro: `Error Code: 1136. Column count doesn't match value count at row` .... Que significa... A contagem de colunas não corresponde à contagem de valores na linha